# Import HDFS data to Opentsdb

Tags: hdfs, bigdata, opentsdb

I would like to know if there is a possibility to import data directly from HDFS to Opentsdb. Could you please give me some examples/hints?

I tried using exec with no successful results:

```
hadoop jar path.jar org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool -find hdfs:///path -type f -name 'part*' -mmin -5 -exec path/opentsdb-master/build/tsdb import {} \;

-find: Fatal internal error
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.find.Exec.initialise(Exec.java:109)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.find.BaseExpression.initialise(BaseExpression.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Find.processArguments(Find.java:383)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:255)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at org.apache.solr.hadoop.HdfsFindTool.main(HdfsFindTool.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each TSD uses the open source database HBase to store and retrieve time-series data. Now you can have your HDFS data into HBase using HBase shell  or Java api. If you are using other data base instead of HBase you need to use sqoop to put HDFS data into your database.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. You mean write the data directly into the HBase tables used by OpenTSDB?

Comment: yes, write the data directly into the HBase tables used by OpenTSDB

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write hdfs data directly to HBase for time-series data store by opentsdb. You need to take care of couple of things: 
OpenTSDB has a special time-series format like composite rowkey concept and delta time elapsed. I am not sure what format is your data in HDFS. Best option is to write script in Java that read data from HDFS and write to HBase in OpenTSDB format. You need to creat metrics and tags as well.